# How can I show a marker in google map using gmaps-autocomplete-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am using gmaps-autocomplete-rails gem in an address field, it works fine and show the map when I input an address in the partial (_form), but how I can show this marker in the view?... I have to do something else or use another gem to show the marker in the view (show.html.erb)?... I need to add some code in the controller?

---

**Model:**

```
geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng
after_validation :geocode, :reverse_geocode, :if => :address_changed?

reverse_geocoded_by :lat, :lng do |obj,results|
 if geo = results.first
  obj.street = geo.address
  obj.city  = geo.city
  obj.state  = geo.state
  obj.country = geo.country
end
```

**Partial _form (address field):**

```
= f.input :address, input_html: { id: 'gmaps-input-address'}, placeholder: 'Start typing a place...', label: 'Location Missing'

....
#gmaps-canvas
```

**Application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
//= require gmaps-auto-complete
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
  var completer;

  completer = new GmapsCompleter({
    mapElem: "#gmaps-canvas", 
    zoomLevel: 5, 
    mapType: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    pos: [41.877, 12.480],
    inputField: '#gmaps-input-address',
    errorField: '#gmaps-error',
    debugOn: false
 });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
before_action :find_mark, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
....

def create
    @mark = Mark.create(mark_params)

    if @mark.save
        redirect_to @mark
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def update
    if @mark.update(mark_params)
        redirect_to @mark
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private

def mark_params
    params.require(:mark).permit(:address, :lat, :lng, :street, :city, :state, :country)
end

def find_mark
    @mark = Mark.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Show us some code; show your efforts!

Comment: Solved! -> using the gem gmaps4rails